# Can I use 2uF or 10uF capacitor instead of a 1uF with the LP2951 voltage regulator?

Tags: power, capacitor

I want to learn to program and use microcontrollers, and therefore I'm setting up a small power supply. The voltage regulator I've selected says I need a 1uF capacitor at the input pin.

So my question is, is this the exact value I need or is it the minimum? Can I use a 2uF or even a 10uF capacitor instead?

I'm planning on using a 9V battery as the power source.

EDIT:

The voltage regulator is the [LP2951](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp2951.pdf).
See page 15 and down.

However, I've been looking around a little more, and I wondered if I can use this regulator instead? http://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&itemSeq=156827308&uq=635456207616008876

Does it matter that its 800 mA instead of 100 mA on the Texas Instruments Regulator?

Comment: To be able to help you, we need more information. What's the part number for the regulator? Can you give us the link to the source that states that the 1uF capacitor is needed?

Comment: u can use 10uF . in the same page there is a sentense "There are no ESR
requirements for this capacitor, and the capacitance can be increased without limit.
"

Comment: I think both of your digikey links are broken. I've removed the first one because we can tell which regulator you're using because of the 2nd link (the PDF). But there's no way for us to tell which 2nd regulator you're talking about. In any case, it's probably best if you ask about the 2nd regulator in a separate question. That's how our site works. It's a bit different from other forums out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a bigger capacitor on the regulator input (and typically anywhere that they're used to smooth out supply voltage spikes or ripples). And you can use regulators rated for higher currents; that's the maximum it's capable of but it won't push in more current than what the circuit consumes.